# Getting the next set of letters from a sequence in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython

I am working on a program that identifies ORFs from a sequence. I seem to be stumbling upon an error while the program is supposed to be analyzing the codons from the sequence.
My code is:

```
def __init__(self,sequence):
    self.sequence = Seq(sequence)
    self.reverse = self.sequence.reverse_complement()
    self.sequence = str(self.sequence)
    self.stopcodons = ["TAG", "TAA", "TGA"]
    self.start = 'ATG'
    self.length = 0
    self.result = ("+",0,0,0,0)

def codon(self,frame):
    start = frame
    while start +3 <=len(self.sequence):
        yield (self.sequence[start:start+3],start)
        start += 3
    #print (start)

def direction(self):
    direction = "+"
    for frame in range(3):
      self.ORF(frame, direction)
    direction = "-"
    for frame in range(3):
        self.sequence = self.reverse
        self.ORF(frame, direction)
    SeqAnalyzer.results()

def ORF(self, frame, direction):
    orf_beg = 0
    codon_frame = self.codon(frame)
    while True:
        i, index = next(codon_frame)
        if i in self.start or not self.start and i not in self.stopcodons:
            orf_beg = index + 1
        elif i in self.stopcodons:
            orf_ending = index + 3
            length = (orf_ending - orf_beg) + 1
            if length > self.length:
                self.length = length
                self.result = (direction, frame, orf_beg, orf_ending, length)
                print(self.result)
            break
def results(self):
    print("'{}{:+d} {:>5d}..{:>5d} {:>5d}'" .format(self.result))
```

When running it I get an error of:

```
File "C:/Users/Alex/OneDrive/Python/Lab 5/findORFs.py", line 33, in direction

self.ORF(frame, direction)
File "C:/Users/Alex/OneDrive/Python/Lab 5/findORFs.py", line 44, in ORF

i, index = next(codon_frame)
StopIteration
```

The problem seems to be coming from my Next(codon_frame) but have no idea how I would go about fixing that.

Comment: a `StopIteration` error just means that you've hit your last item in your iterator. just put that line inside a try block and then handle the exception by breaking your loop/whatever you need to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
codon_frame = self.codon(frame)
while True:
    i, index = next(codon_frame)`
```

you should probably be doing:

```
for i, index in self.codon(frame):
```

If for some reason you want to keep doing it manually, then you need to wrap the `next()` call with a `try/except`:

```
try:
    i, index = next(codon_frame)
except StopIteration:
    break
```

Comment: @lamazibiji: `self.stopcodons` is a list, `self.start` is a string, and `i` is a `Seq` -- typically when using `in` the left item needs to be the same type as the things you are checking against; so `i` should be a string, or `self.stopcodons` should be a list of `Seq`.

Comment: thanks for the response Ethan! I rewrote i and self.stopcodons as str() and the code now runs. This shouldn't affect my results though right?

Comment: also I am trying to print the results using ""{:+d} {:>5d}..{:>5d} {:>5d}" but my results are stored as str. how could i make it work with format code d?

Comment: @lamazibiji: convert back to a number:  `"%d" % int("10")`, for example.

Comment: @lamazibiji: I don't know if the switch to `str` will affect your results.  You'll want to have a few tests in place so you can check.  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ethan! I got the whole thing to work. I just have one more question. Do you know how I would go about having my program run continuously until it finds all ORFs? i can't figure out where I should make it loop

Comment: @lamazibiji:  I can't see enough of your code to answer that, but I know it's a question that comes up a lot.  Try searching, and if nothing helps post a new question.  :)   Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
codon_frame = self.codon(frame)
while True:
    i, index = next(codon_frame)
```

With:

```
for i, index in self.codon(frame):
```

Comment: That yields me with  new error:
    line 34, in ORF
    if i in self.start or not self.start and i not in self.stopcodons:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Seq